# Unhandled 'error' event Broken @import declaration

Tags: gulp, laravel-elixir

Hello I am new to gulpjs and i'm finally getting a hang of it, that is till i got this error while running **gulp --production**:

```
events.js.:85
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: Broken @import declaration
```

This is followed by a list of files.
I do not get this error when i run **gulp** alone.

I traced it to this css file:

```
/* iCheck plugin skins
----------------------------------- */
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
/*
@import url("minimal/minimal.css");
@import url("minimal/red.css");
@import url("minimal/green.css");
@import url("minimal/blue.css");
@import url("minimal/aero.css");
@import url("minimal/grey.css");
@import url("minimal/orange.css");
@import url("minimal/yellow.css");
@import url("minimal/pink.css");
@import url("minimal/purple.css");
*/

@import url("square/_all.css");
/*
@import url("square/square.css");
@import url("square/red.css");
@import url("square/green.css");
@import url("square/blue.css");
@import url("square/aero.css");
@import url("square/grey.css");
@import url("square/orange.css");
@import url("square/yellow.css");
@import url("square/pink.css");
@import url("square/purple.css");
*/

@import url("flat/_all.css");
/*
@import url("flat/flat.css");
@import url("flat/red.css");
@import url("flat/green.css");
@import url("flat/blue.css");
@import url("flat/aero.css");
@import url("flat/grey.css");
@import url("flat/orange.css");
@import url("flat/yellow.css");
@import url("flat/pink.css");
@import url("flat/purple.css");
*/

@import url("line/_all.css");
/*
@import url("line/line.css");
@import url("line/red.css");
@import url("line/green.css");
@import url("line/blue.css");
@import url("line/aero.css");
@import url("line/grey.css");
@import url("line/orange.css");
@import url("line/yellow.css");
@import url("line/pink.css");
@import url("line/purple.css");
*/

@import url("polaris/polaris.css");

@import url("futurico/futurico.css");
```

And i did verify if all the files being imported existed.
I dunno what is wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your Gulp file to know what plugins your using and what your trying to achieve from them, but at a guess your probably using the gulp plugin 'gulp-minify-css' which is just a wrapper for the 'clean-css' Node library so checking out those projects github issue pages would be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is five months old, but the resolution is to remove ALL comments from the iCheck script, like this...

```
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
@import url("square/_all.css");
@import url("flat/_all.css");
@import url("line/_all.css");
@import url("polaris/polaris.css");
@import url("futurico/futurico.css");
```

It appears the minification process get's choked up on the comments syntax. That's what I had to do in order to get build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing the directories and files in the folder:

**Example:**

I was importing @import `"icons/font.css"`

And in the css folder it did not have the folder
  `icons/font.css`